# processing - get sketch to recognize xtion kinect device

Tags: kinect, processing, openni, openkinect

I have a processing sketch which worked with a microsoft Kinect and which I am now attempting to get to work with an Asus Xtion RGB+D camera. I am getting the attached error. This is my code:

```
// Daniel Shiffman
// Kinect Point Cloud example
// http://www.shiffman.net
// https://github.com/shiffman/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/java/processing

import org.openkinect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;
import muehlseife.*; //<- import library
import java.io.*;
import processing.opengl.*;

octaneRenderer oct; //<- setup variable
boolean exportObj = false;


// Kinect Library object
Kinect kinect;

float a = 0;

// Size of kinect image
int w = 640;
int h = 480;

// writing state indicator
boolean write = false;

// threshold filter initial value
int fltValue = 950;


// "recording" object. each vector element holds a coordinate map vector
Vector <Object> recording = new Vector<Object>(); 


// We'll use a lookup table so that we don't have to repeat the math over and over
float[] depthLookUp = new float[2048];

void setup() {
  //size(800,600,P3D);
  size(800,600,OPENGL);
  kinect = new Kinect(this);
  kinect.start();
  kinect.enableDepth(true);
  // We don't need the grayscale image in this example
  // so this makes it more efficient
  kinect.processDepthImage(false);

...
```

Any idea of how to get the xtion to work?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Daniel Shiffman's Kinect wrapper is for OpenKinect/libfreenect which has a driver only for Xbox Kinect (not for Kinect for Windows/Asus Xtion/Primesense Sensor)

You might need to use OpenNI and the PrimeSense Drivers. 
Since you're using Processing I recommend using the [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) wrapper.
The only catch is OpenNI 2 was released recently but SimpleOpenNI isn't updated 
for that so it will only work with the older (1.5.x) SDK. Luckily the [SimpleOpenNI
downloads](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/list) also includes the installers you need.

Try this first:

1. Use the hardware/middleware/etc. installer provided by SimpleOpenNI
2. Install the Processing library
3. Run a simple sample to see if it works)

Hopefully it should all be fine.

If not you might need to install OpenNI/NITE/Sensor (not SensorKinect)
manually one by one in this order. You should be able to download
the individual installers from the [official OpenNI site](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/).
Before you move to Processing, you should be run one of the OpenNI samples
(like SimpleNiViewer) to check if everything is fine up to this stage.

I've seen [Everyware's](http://everyware.kr/home/onedotzero-x-everyware/) updated Pink Cloud app running in Processing
and they were using Asus Xtion sensors so hopefully you'll be using the 
Xtion sensor with Processing soon.
[image: Everyware Pink Cloud installation]